# Syntax Error JSON.parse ajax.responsetext (Spring,jquery,ajax,gson)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, spring

I am using Netbeans & spring framework4.0.1,without annotation only normal model&view

When i try to send a JSON to the jsp page & using ajax function call back , i am unable to parse the response text, gives me this error
"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 12 column 1 of the JSON data"
This is the controller code

```
 public ModelAndView contentlistObjective(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("createsettings");
           List<Content> contents = new ArrayList<>();
     //       JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
           try {
             DriverManagerDataSource dataSource;
            dataSource = (DriverManagerDataSource)this.getBean("dataSource",hsr.getServletContext());
            this.cn = dataSource.getConnection();  
                 Statement st = this.cn.createStatement();
                 String objectiveid = null;
                    objectiveid = hsr.getParameter("seleccion3");         
              ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("SELECT name,id FROM         public.content where public.content.id IN (select public.objective_content.content_id from public.objective_content where public.objective_content.objective_id = "+objectiveid+")");

           while (rs1.next())
            {
     Content eq = new Content();
     contents.add(eq);
//   obj.put("name", rs1.getString("name"));

            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error leyendo contents: " + ex);
        }
       Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
       String json = gson.toJson(contents);
       hsr1.setContentType("application/json");

//      System.out.print(json);
//      json = json.replaceAll("\n", "");
//      json = json.trim();
//      json = json.substring(1,json.length()-1);
//      json = json.replace("\\","");
       mv.addObject(json);
        return mv;
    }
```

When i debug json that i am returning has this value 
[
  {
    "name": "newspaper"
  },
  {
    "name": "novel"
  }
]
Below is the JSP code

```
function comboSelectionObjective()
            {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) //mozilla
                {
                    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest(); //No Internet explorer
                } else
                {
                    ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }             

                ajax.onreadystatechange = funcionCallBackContent;
             var seleccion3 = document.getElementById("objective").value;
                ajax.open("GET", "createsetting.htm?select=contentlistObjective&seleccion3=" + seleccion3, true);
                ajax.send("");
}
function funcionCallBackContent()
            {
                if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
                    if (ajax.status===200){
                   var data =JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
                 console.log(data);
                 }
```

i am using gson library, i used before it Json simple but it gave exactly the same error
also i tried to replace all escape characters and did not work either

Is the problem that i am not using annotations?

Appreciate your help

Comment: Your method is returning a ModelAndView object. It has to return the json string, not a view.

Comment: i am returning an object that is the json string, is there another way to do it?

Comment: You are not returning a json object. You are setting the json string in your model and then returning the view "createsettings".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the json string instead of a `ModelAndView` object.

When calling the method `addOjbect` at the `ModelAndView` object what you are doing is add or overwrite an attribute to the model.

[ModelAndView api](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html)

Returning the `ModelAndView` you are returning basically a string with the view name you want to show back, so you are returning a html page, not a json object.

What you need to do is return a json string. So it should be something like:

```
@ResponseBody
public String contentlistObjective(HttpServletRequest hsr, HttpServletResponse hsr1) throws Exception {

  .... your code

  hsr1.setContentType("application/json");

  //You should double check before returning. Just an example.
  return gson.toJson(contents);
}
```

[Mapping the response body with the @ResponseBody annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-responsebody)

> The @ResponseBody annotation [...] can be put on a method and
>   indicates that the return type should be written straight to the HTTP
>   response body (and not placed in a Model, or interpreted as a view
>   name).

If you do not want to use any anotation at all and go with the old fashioned way, then you have to put the json content directly in the response output. Something like:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(contents);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: thanks so much for your reply, how do i retrieve this string in Jquery, using ajax.response text? do i need to JSON parse it

Comment: @Norhan Yes, you should get the json string using ajax.response. If you do not parse it you are going to have just a string. If you parse it, it will be transformed into a javascript object. So, it is up to you. As you can imagine it is much easier work with a javascript object or array instead of just a string. Accept my answer if it is working, please.

Comment: i add @ response body  to the controller method, now it will not even enter in the function call back , it goes to the controller but the response is not working

Comment: i think you are on to something, you are right the problem is that it returns the whole page, but how to convert the code from model & view to annotation based

Comment: What spring version are you using? Update your question including your spring configuration, please.

Comment: spring framework 4.0.1, do i need to enable annotation by adding this to application context <mvc:annotation-driven />

Comment: when i add it the project wont compile

Comment: i managed to place the HTTP 404 - /JSON_test/WEB-INF/jsp/[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;newspaper&quot;},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;novel&quot;}].jsp

Comment: i placed the <mvc:annotation-driven /> in dispatcher servlet & now it does not result in compilation error, the rpoblem is that the response is now   HTTP 404 - /JSON_test/WEB-INF/jsp/[{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;newspaper&quot;},{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;novel&quot;}].jsp as you can see it is placing the json string in the url so it returns 404 status

Comment: I do not get you.  Difficult to read your comments. Could you update your question, please? Include your spring config.

Comment: i converted the whole controller to annotation based and now it works, you were right, i can not use Model & View to pass a JSON